# In these caching scenarios, where is the code executed?

Tags: caching, redis

I'm reading about caching strategies such as cache-aside, write-through, write-back, ...  In the specific cases of write-through and write-back, it is implied that the cache itself is responsible for writing to the database and the event queue, respectively (For full context, here is the article -  https://github.com/donnemartin/system-design-primer#when-to-update-the-cache)

For example, write-through is illustrated as

Application code:

```
set_user(12345, {"foo":"bar"})
```

Cache code:

```
def set_user(user_id, values):
    user = db.query("UPDATE Users WHERE id = {0}", user_id, values)
    cache.set(user_id, user)
```

For now, let's assume we're using Redis.

*In the concrete example above, is the hypothetical `set_user` function invoked on the Redis client's machine, or on the Redis server?*

Now, there *seems* to be ways to invoke custom logic on the Redis server, e.g., by writing Lua scripts, but I'm skeptical that that's done in practice in order to implement this caching strategy, partly because I've never heard of anyone doing it.

I've seen other articles showing this strategy is implemented solely on the Redis client's machine, but I'm not sure what resources to believe at this point.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's part of the application. In fact, it would be more appropriate to call the example "data store code", instead of "cache code". The `set_user` method belongs to a base `UserStore` class, with different implementations based on data store type, write policy etc. For "write-through", it would be:

```
class WriteThroughUserStore(UserStore):

    def __init__(self, cache_user_store, db_user_store):
        self.cache_user_store = cache_user_store
        self.db_user_store = db_user_store

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        return self.cache_user_store.get_user(user_id)

    def set_user(self, user):
        self.db_user_store.set_user(user)
        self.cache_user_store.set_user(user)
```

The key point of "write-through" is that the write operation is confirmed complete only after writing data to both cache and database synchronously. The order does not matter: you could update cache first, or update database first, or even do them in parallel.

Comment: Good, thorough answer.  This clears up the other strategies as well.  Thanks!